# WPF DataGrid visible on selected row in another DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have found a few examples for hiding or showing elements on a selected row in a nested DataGrid structure however I'm trying to do something different and having trouble finding the right binding.

I have two datagrids and I want the second one only visible when the first one has a selected row.  I like to use the BooleanToVisibilityConverter as this seems to be the cleanest solution.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="GalaxyCreator.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GalaxyCreator.ViewModel"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             mc:Ignorable="d ignore">

    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewportControl/ViewportControlResourceDictionary.xaml"/>

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!--Global View Model Locator-->
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                             d:IsDataSource="True" />
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

extract of my implementation xaml

```
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="450"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <DataGrid Name="OrderGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Job.Orders}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Order}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Order"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DefaultOrder}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Default"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedOrder.Parameters, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True" MinColumnWidth="250" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,500,0"
                          Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Source={x:Reference OrderGrid}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            </Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaxyCreator.Dialogs.DialogService;
using GalaxyCreator.Model.JobEditor;
using GalaxyCreator.Model.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace GalaxyCreator.Dialogs.JobEditor
{
    class JobEditorDetailViewModel : DialogViewModelBase
    {
        public Job Job { get; set; }

        public ShipSize? JobCategoryShipSize
        {
            get
            {
                if(Job.JobCategory.ShipSize == null)
                {
                    return ShipSize.NONE;
                }
                return Job.JobCategory.ShipSize;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value == ShipSize.NONE)
                {
                    Job.JobCategory.ShipSize = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Job.JobCategory.ShipSize = value;
                }                
            }
        }

        public ShipSize? ShipShipSize
        {
            get
            {
                if (Job.Ship.Size == null)
                {
                    return ShipSize.NONE;
                }
                return Job.Ship.Size;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == ShipSize.NONE)
                {
                    Job.Ship.Size = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Job.Ship.Size = value;
                }
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand<object> _saveCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand<object> SaveCommand
        {
            get { return _saveCommand; }
            set { _saveCommand = value; }
        }

        private RelayCommand<object> _cancelCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand<object> CancelCommand
        {
            get { return _cancelCommand; }
            set { _cancelCommand = value; }
        }

        private RelayCommand<object> _jobCategoryTagUpdateCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand<object> JobCategoryTagUpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_jobCategoryTagUpdateCommand == null)
                {
                    _jobCategoryTagUpdateCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((param) => UpdateTagOnJobCategory(param));
                }

                return _jobCategoryTagUpdateCommand;
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand<object> _jobLocationsFactionUpdateCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand<object> JobLocationFactionsUpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_jobLocationsFactionUpdateCommand == null)
                {
                    _jobLocationsFactionUpdateCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((param) => UpdateLocationsOnJobLocation(param));
                }

                return _jobLocationsFactionUpdateCommand;
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand<object> _shipFactionsTagUpdateCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand<object> ShipFactionsUpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_shipFactionsTagUpdateCommand == null)
                {
                    _shipFactionsTagUpdateCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((param) => UpdateFactionsOnShip(param));
                }

                return _shipFactionsTagUpdateCommand;
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand<object> _shipTagsUpdateCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand<object> ShipTagsUpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_shipTagsUpdateCommand == null)
                {
                    _shipTagsUpdateCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((param) => UpdateTagsOnShip(param));
                }

                return _shipTagsUpdateCommand;
            }
        }

        private JobOrder _selectedOrder;
        public JobOrder SelectedOrder
        {
            get { return _selectedOrder; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _selectedOrder, value);
            }
        }

        public String JobCategoryTags
        {
            get
            {
                if(this.Job.JobCategory.Tags != null)
                {
                    string Result = "{";
                    foreach (Tag Tag in this.Job.JobCategory.Tags)
                    {
                        Result = Result + " " + Tag.ToString() + " ";
                    }
                    Result = Result + "}";
                    return Result;
                }
                return "";
            }
        }

        public String ShipTags
        {
            get
            {
                if(this.Job.Ship.Tags != null)
                {
                    string Result = "{";
                    foreach (Tag Tag in this.Job.Ship.Tags)
                    {
                        Result = Result + " " + Tag.ToString() + " ";
                    }
                    Result = Result + "}";
                    return Result;
                }
                return "";
            }
        }

        public String JobLocationFactions
        {
            get
            {
                if(this.Job.JobLocation.Factions != null)
                {
                    string Result = "{";
                    foreach (Faction Faction in this.Job.JobLocation.Factions)
                    {
                        Result = Result + " " + Faction.ToString() + " ";
                    }
                    Result = Result + "}";
                    return Result;
                }
                return "";
            }
        }

        public String ShipFactions
        {
            get
            {
                if(this.Job.Ship.Factions != null)
                {
                    string Result = "{";
                    foreach (Faction Faction in this.Job.Ship.Factions)
                    {
                        Result = Result + " " + Faction.ToString() + " ";
                    }
                    Result = Result + "}";
                    return Result;
                }
                return "";
            }
        }

        private IList<SubordinateItem> _subordinateItems = new List<SubordinateItem>();
        public IList<SubordinateItem> SubordinateItems
        {
            get { return _subordinateItems; }
            set
            {
                Set(ref _subordinateItems, value);
            }
        }

        public JobEditorDetailViewModel(string message, Job job) : base(message)
        {
            this.Job = job;
            this._saveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnSaveClicked(parent));
            this._cancelCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((parent) => OnCancelClicked(parent));
            foreach (String subordinate in Job.Subordinates)
            {
                _subordinateItems.Add(new SubordinateItem(subordinate));
            }
        }

        private void OnSaveClicked(object parameter)
        {
            this.Job.Subordinates.Clear();
            foreach (SubordinateItem item in _subordinateItems)
            {
                this.Job.Subordinates.Add(item.Value);
            }
            this.CloseDialogWithResult(parameter as Window, DialogResult.Yes);
        }

        private void OnCancelClicked(object parameter)
        {
            this.CloseDialogWithResult(parameter as Window, DialogResult.No);
        }

        private void UpdateTagOnJobCategory(object param)
        {
            if(param != null)
            {
                Tag tagParam = (Tag)param;
                if (Job.JobCategory.Tags.Contains(tagParam))
                {
                    Job.JobCategory.Tags.Remove(tagParam);
                }
                else
                {
                    Job.JobCategory.Tags.Add(tagParam);
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("JobCategoryTags");
            }
        }

        private void UpdateLocationsOnJobLocation(object param)
        {
            if (param != null)
            {
                Faction factionParam = (Faction)param;
                if (Job.JobLocation.Factions.Contains(factionParam))
                {
                    Job.JobLocation.Factions.Remove(factionParam);
                }
                else
                {
                    Job.JobLocation.Factions.Add(factionParam);
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("JobLocationFactions");
            }
        }

        private void UpdateFactionsOnShip(object param)
        {
            if (param != null)
            {
                Faction factionParam = (Faction)param;
                if (Job.Ship.Factions.Contains(factionParam))
                {
                    Job.Ship.Factions.Remove(factionParam);
                }
                else
                {
                    Job.Ship.Factions.Add(factionParam);
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("ShipFactions");
            }
        }

        private void UpdateTagsOnShip(object param)
        {
            if (param != null)
            {
                Tag tagParam = (Tag)param;
                if (Job.Ship.Tags.Contains(tagParam))
                {
                    Job.Ship.Tags.Remove(tagParam);
                }
                else
                {
                    Job.Ship.Tags.Add(tagParam);
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("ShipTags");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want the second datagrid to be hidden until I click a row in the first datagrid, the SelectedItem is set and I want the second datgrid to show itself.  At the moment the second datagrid never shows and stays hidden.

All the examples I have looked at uptill now use RelativeSource and handle with some elements nested in a datagrid.  So please do not mark this as a duplicate question cause it isn't.  I have been searching for an hour and read a few examples.  I think I have an idea how it works I just can't get the binding right I'm a java dev this is a hobby project in C# so I'm learning by examples

Comment: Could not understand what is not working.   Can you be explicit and provide the current behavior and behavior you expect ?  Also, how IsSelected property is being set and are we raising NotifyPropertyChange when it is set ?

Comment: I have updated the datagrid with more information.  My entire ViewModel and my expected behavior below it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, what wasn't clear to me is that you can go up a hierarchy even if it's not the same component type.  So I could go up to Grid and then Back down again to the appropriate DataGrid.  Once I knew this it was easy

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="450"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Order information" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Label Content="Parameters" Grid.Column="1" />
    <DataGrid Name="OrderGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Job.Orders}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Order}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Order"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DefaultOrder}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Default"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedOrder.Parameters, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" MinColumnWidth="250" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,500,0"
              Visibility="{Binding 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, 
                  Path=OrderGrid, 
                  Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: don't know what to say though, cause it actually is working as I expect it to work.  First there is no second datagrid, I click a row in the first one, second one appears with the right data inside